# MongoError: Found unexpected fields after $each in $addToSet

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoError: Found unexpected fields after $each in $addToSet

```
      await Profile.updateOne(
        { ref },
        {
          $addToSet: {
            "contact": {
              $each: [ "addr" ],
              $position: 0,
            },
          },
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#mongodb-update-up.-position) is a modifier for [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#modifiers) only, and cannot be used with [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet).